# express-session variable is changed after loading api

Tags: javascript, node.js, session, express, express-session

I am a newbie in expressjs, my question is related to the express-session.

the app.js is below, in the package.json, I have express and express-session installed.

If I go to 'localhost:3000', in the console, the req.session.flag value will change like this:

---

*One before: undefined

One after: 1

Two before: 1

Two after: 2*

after that, if I go to 'localhost:3000/three', in the console, the req.session.flag value will change like this:

---

*Three before: 2

Three after: 3*

if I refreash  'localhost:3000/three' at this point, the value of req.session.flag will be 2 but not 3.

---

*Three before: 2

Three after: 3*

Why it is the case? the value of req.session.flag is changed to 3 from the previous point, why in the console it begins at 2?

and if i go to 'localhost:3000', the value of req.session.flag will start at 2 as well, why it is the case?

---

*One before: 2

One after: 1

Two before: 1

Two after: 2*

Thanks!

```js
var express = require('express');
var session = require("express-session");
var post = require('./routes/post');
var app = express();

var port = 3000;

app.use(session({secret:'fdsadfasdfdsafdsafdsafdsafd', saveUninitialized:false, resave: false}));



app.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
  console.log("********************************");
  console.log("One before: "+req.session.flag);
  req.session.flag = 1;
  console.log("One after: "+req.session.flag);
      next();
},
function (req, res, next) {
    console.log("Two before: "+req.session.flag);
  req.session.flag = 2;
  console.log("Two after: "+req.session.flag);

var html="<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>Hello world</title></head><body ><h1>Hello world</h1></body></html>";
  res.send(html); 
});


app.get('/three', function (req, res, next) {
    console.log("********************************");
  console.log("Three before: "+req.session.flag);
req.session.flag = 3;
console.log("Three after: "+req.session.flag);
});


app.listen(port);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The session does not get saved in your `/three` endpoint. This is because you don't send back any response (not even an empty one).

From the `express-session` docs:

> Session.save()
>
> Save the session back to the store, replacing the contents on the
>   store with the contents in memory (though a store may do something
>   else--consult the store's documentation for exact behavior).
>
> This method is automatically called at the end of the HTTP response if
>   the session data has been altered (though this behavior can be altered
>   with various options in the middleware constructor). Because of this,
>   typically this method does not need to be called.
>
> There are some cases where it is useful to call this method, for
>   example, long- lived requests or in WebSockets.

Since you don't call `res.send` (or simply `res.end`), the request will eventually timeout and the session won't be saved.

Due to the asynchronous nature of JavaScript with callbacks, express can't just send a default response. You must always manually send one.

Comment: Thanks for the detail explanation, very appriciated